# Calculation of Value at a Point on an Infinite Plane of Randomly Distributed Wavefunctions?

Tags: probability, geometry

I have a bit of a weird and complicated question that I can't seem to answer myself. Also I don't know how to use formatting so sorry if this is annoying to read. Assume an infinite (x, y) plane populated with infinitely many randomly placed points with value 1 such that on average there is 1 of these points per 10000. We will call these n-points. Now, assume each point on the plane (x, y) has a value calculated such that it is equal to the sum over all n-points of ((cos(d)+1)/(d+1)) where d is the distance between the point (x, y) the n-point. Is there a closed form solution to this problem f(x, y), and if not, what is the most computationally efficient way to approximate the value of a given point (x, y)? Also, if the value of a point diverges to infinity, consider replacing the above sum with ((cos(d)+1)/(d^2+1)). The function that determines the distribution is important I know, but I don't care about the specifics as long as the distribution of points is random enough and isn't uniform, so choose whatever function that fits these criteria that is easiest to work with. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).